# NSAttributedString crash on init, but why?

Tags: swift, encoding, nsattributedstring

Sometimes this thing crashes but I don't know why and when. 
Does someone have an idea?

```
extension String {
var htmlDecoded: String? {

    if let encodedData = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) as Data? {
        let attributedOptions = [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                  NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue] as [String : Any]
        do {
            let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData,
                                                          options: attributedOptions,
                                                          documentAttributes: nil)
            return attributedString.string

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("ERROR: ", error.localizedDescription)

            return self
        }
    }
    return self
}
}
```

This is the error I get from HockeyApp

```
function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed and Exploded> of @nonobjc (extension in UIKit):__C.NSAttributedString.init(data: Foundation.Data, options: [Swift.String : Any], documentAttributes: Swift.AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<__C.NSDictionary?>?) throws -> __C.NSAttributedString (String+html.swift:0)

function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded> of (extension in Podcat_2):Swift.String.htmlDecoded.getter : Swift.String? (String+html.swift:0)
```

Comment: It looks like you are using an old version of `Swift` as the above code will not compile with `Xcode 9.4.1`. Can you provide some sample `html` string that fails?

Comment: Use Swift 3.3, then it will build. 

This is the problem. I don't know when it crashes. This code should work with podcast metadata. But i don't know the crashing html.

Comment: See the [discussion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1524613-init#discussion) of `init(data:options:documentAttributes:)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommand you to upgrade to swift 4. Font are changed a lot in swift 4 and it's better to make the change earlier.

Here is my swift 4 version that works great for me to convert html string to `NSAttributedString`. You can then call `.string` to get the string itself.

```
extension String {
    func htmlAttributedString() -> NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return nil }
        guard let html = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
            data: data,
            options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
            documentAttributes: nil) else { return nil }
        return html
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question.